# IOS silent notifications settings not found

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

The above URL says the place where you can Upload your APNs authentication key to Firebase project to start receiving silent notifications in the IOS app. But, I cannot find the option to upload in firebase -> Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging as it says that I should find. Am I missing anything? Is this deprecated? FYI I have enabled push notifications and remote notification in the background modes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have at least editor level privilege in the project to see the IOS app configuration in Cloud Messaging